# powershell get file location from user

Tags: powershell, automation, powershell-cmdlet, copy-item

Hi i am trying to automate something for testing purposes. I have a sample.xml file which i need to transfer to some folder , which is done by the user manually. so i am trying to automate this via powershell.

The file location should be selected by the user and i want to do

**Copy-Item -Path $fileLocation -Destination $dest**

i wrote this piece of code, i tried hardcoding the root path and capturing the location of file alone via a filter, i can see that path is correctly printed but it is not getting accepted by the Copy-Item . it throws path is null.

Here's the piece of code i wrote

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$path
)

[string]$path = get-childitem -path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Demo\Sample" -Filter POsample01.xml -recurse | % {Write-Host $_.FullName}
Write-Host $path
Copy-Item -Path $path -Destination "D:\powershell"
```

the write-host prints the actual location of the sample file !

Answer (score 0):

Why would the user need to do this manually?

If PoSH Remoting is configured, and you are an administrator, you can navigate the file system remotely, then you can copy / move the file remotely.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'SomeTaregHostname' -ScriptBlock {
[CmdletBinding()]

Param
(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$path
)

    [string]$path = get-childitem -path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Demo\Sample" -Filter POsample01.xml -recurse | % {$_.FullName}
    $path
    Copy-Item -Path $path -Destination "D:\powershell"
}
```

You also should not use Write-Host just to output to the screen, as that is not really needed. Well, unless you are using it to display colorized text. The default is output to screen.

If you need to send things down the pipeline, then Write-Host clears the buffer and you'd have nothing to send. So, remember this...

If pipeline (passing info/objects to something else) is to be used - Never use Write-Host.

If you do this in a true automated way, this sort of thing is invisible to the user.

> Write-Host Considered Harmful - by PowerShell founder Jeffrey Snover
>
> Start-Process
>   'http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful'
>
> When you are writing or reviewing PowerShell scripts, I’d like you to
>   remember  the following rule of thumb:
>
> ◾ Using Write-Host is almost always wrong.
>
> Write-Host is almost always the wrong thing to do because it
>   interferes with  automation. There are typically two reasons why
>   people use Write-Host:
>
> Lot's of other articles exist on the topic. In earlier versions of
>   PoSH,  Write-Host could not be used in pipeline, as the moment yo use
>   it the data is  gone from the buffer.
>
> However, in PoSHv5 Jeffrey Snover now says...
>
> With PowerShell v5 Write-Host no longer "kills puppies". data is
>   captured into  info stream
>
> Start-Process
>   'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Information?view=powershell-5.1'
>
> Description
>
> The Write-Information cmdlet specifies how Windows PowerShell handles
>   information  stream data for a command.
>
> Windows PowerShell 5.0 introduces a new, structured information stream
>   (number  6 in Windows PowerShell streams) that you can use to transmit
>   structured data  between a script and its callers (or hosting
>   environment). Write-Information  lets you add an informational message
>   to the stream, and specify how Windows  PowerShell handles information
>   stream data for a command.

Comment: i cannot do that from remote and i dont want to . I want a powershell which on run , copies the file to $dest from the $source location . The destination is the same , but the source can change , i want that alone to be able to be selected by the user . Thanks

Comment: Well, it's of course your choice. So, your comment  means, you are placing this script on the user workstation and they are to run this script or you are using a scheduled task and the user makes the selection.

Comment: yeah they need to run this script. i am not using any sheduled task. All i want is them to choose the root directory, inside that it may contain many subfolders , in among them exists my sample.xml file . i have to copy it to some destination location . How to do it ? Remember that root directory may change / user . so it alone should be entered by them.

Comment: Any help here is appereciated ?

Comment: IF they are running this and you never know what the root path would be, that means you have to scan the drive for something you know. Just use GCI and exclude all the dirs. you don want to look thru. If you know what the root path name is then you just look for that using GCI and the -directory parameter. From there you should be able to run your code.

Comment: Yes man , i want them to be able to select the root path alone and then i will scan inside that path for the sample.xml file alone using a filter. If i use Read-Host to select a path and that path is not getting accepted by the Copy-Item . it says that the path is null